# v4l-utils for CentOS Stream 8?

Tags: centos, drivers, video, camera, v4l

I have problems with webcam and I need v4l-utils package. As per this page:

https://centos.pkgs.org/7/centos-x86_64/v4l-utils-0.9.5-4.el7.x86_64.rpm.html

It was availbel in CentOS 7 official repos. However for CentOS Stream 8 I cannot find it:

```
$ sudo dnf search v4l-utils
Last metadata expiration check: 13:59:10 ago on Sat 15 May 2021 10:19:51 CEST.
No matches found.
[admin@localhost ~]$ sudo dnf search v4l2-utils
Last metadata expiration check: 13:59:55 ago on Sat 15 May 2021 10:19:51 CEST.
No matches found.
```

1. Why was the package deprecated?
2. What has replaced it?
3. Any other hints for uvcvideo diagnostics?

Comment: maybe try `libv4l-utils` instead? I think this is what works on centos / rhel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was neither replaced nor deprecated. Some packages are just being "missed" from rebuilding for the newer operating system, and there's a fair amount of waiting (even forever) until there are enough requests for it to be built.

Thus you may notice the package is available from a bunch of 3rd party repositories.

Comment: Could you please elaborate on several  most popular, trusted repos? I am not familiar with rpm ecosystem.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I was able to find a repo that holds v4l-utils for CentOS:

```
$ sudo rpm -ivh http://repo.okay.com.mx/centos/8/x86_64/release/okay-release-1-5.el8.noarch.rpm
...
$ sudo dnf install v4l-utils
...
$ v4l2-ctl --list-devices
Chicony USB2.0 Camera: Chicony  (usb-0000:00:0b.0-1):
    /dev/video0
    /dev/video1
```

Beware however that okay repo replaces some standard packages with newer versions which may affect the stability of your system:

```
$ dnf check-upgrade
...
```